# Expose PC playing MP3 files to Android as USB microphone

Tags: android, audio, usb, smartphone, python-sounddevice

Probably an unusual request, but here goes...

I'm trying to create a script (ideally in Python, but open to other options) that will stream an mp3 file from a computer to an Android Phone's microphone input. I guess this would require exposing the computer to the phone as a USB microphone, then playing the mp3 file out of that sound device. I can play the mp3 via `sounddevice` easily enough but don't know where to start setting the phone's mic input as a sound output or vice-versa. I wondered about ADB or something like that, but am well out of my depth now.

Basically I have some voice recordings that I'd like to put into a voice changer app, but the app can only record from the microphone and doesn't have an option to change pre-recorded files.

Maybe someone's seen or done something like this before?